# UIImagePickerController and UINavigationController navigate on completion?

Tags: ios, swift

I've got a `UINavigationController` that brings up a view via `self.setViewControllers([self.homeController], animated: false)`. Home controller has a button to pop a `UIImagePickerController` by signaling the `UINavigationController` via delegate. So the navigation controller calls `self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)`.

This all works well enough, and my image picker pops up. Canceling it does what I expect as well, and takes me back to homeController. However, if I select 'use video', I actually want to navigate to another view. So I did this;

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String:AnyObject]) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {
          self.pushViewController(self.detailController, animated: false)
        })
    }
```

Oddly enough, I see detailController for a brief moment, and then homeController appears. Tracing viewWillLoad/viewWillAppear calls, it seems my detail controller does in fact load, and then appear. Immediately after that, homeController does the same. So I suspect this is a sequencing issue, but given the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` only has two methods in it, I don't see where else I might do this..

Can anyone suggest the right way to accomplish this?

Comment: I assume `self` in this case refers to the `UIImagePIckerController`. As soon as you push the new view, the old one is dismissed, thereby dismissing the DetailController as well. Instead, retain a reference to the UINavigationController / presentingController and present the DetailController on that.

Comment: For example, `let navController = self.presentingViewController!`. Then dismiss, and push the new one onto navController.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was further upstream than I thought -- I was doing logic in viewWillAppear to push a controller. Should have been doing so in viewDidLoad. Moving it did the trick.